# Errors while trying to install pip from terminal

Tags: python-3.x, bash, pip

I am trying to install `pip3` via a bash script/terminal. I am using the following commands:

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
/usr/local/bin/python3.6 get-pip.py
```

When I run these two commands, I get some weird errors that I am not understanding. Can someone please explain what these errors mean and how to fix them (or let me know if there is a better way to install pip3 other than brew)?

```
Operating system: Mac OSX
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1603k  100 1603k    0     0  8216k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 8224k
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pip
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
```

Comment: I think you need to install SSL module in python according to this line: ''pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.''

Comment: Yes, but would I not need pip to install the module?

Comment: Should I just use `easy_install` to get the appropriate version of `pip` that I want? Then go and install things with `pip` from there?

Comment: I think you need to install system module like openssl, I don't know how to do it on MacOS

Comment: I think the error generated from the first command, try without s in https

Comment: @YassineSedrani yes! I think that did it! You can post a full answer and I will mark you correct if you would like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of this error message is the SSL module is missing from your system, you can't perform any request to an `HTTPS` URL, Try without "s" `http` instead of `https`

**OR THE BEST**, install OpenSSL maybe with `brew install openssl` check the official docs for more information, good luck!