# Can't install Pandas in PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pycharm, package

I'm a total newbie with programming. To get startet a little I've tried to install Pandas in PyCharm with `pip install Pandas`. When I try to install it via the Terminal or the Settings I receive the following:

```
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/pandas/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas
```

As I have already installed Pandas for usage in the Jypiter Notebook the mac Terminal gives me the following when typing `pip install pandas`:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.12.0)
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')"))) - skipping
```

Although it looks for me like Pandas is already installed on the computer (the anaconda3 in there troubles me), it is not working with PyCharm.
Im using Python 3.8 with PyCharm 2019.3 and my pip version is 19.0.3

I would be glad about any help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Why did you try this `pip install python`?

Comment: so sorry for the mistake, I ment `pip install pandas` of course

Comment: error shows that you try to install for Python 3.7 - check what version you get with `pip -V` . You may have `pip3.8` to install for Python 3.8 - or you may have to uses `python3.8 -m pip install ...`

Comment: If you're using Anaconda, don't use pip! _the anaconda3 in there troubles me_ Huh, why? In any case, there's no need to mess around with the command line. PyCharm makes it easy to create Conda environments and manage packages through the GUI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Errors while trying to install pip from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911641/errors-while-trying-to-install-pip-from-terminal)

Answer (score 3):

try this please : 
 Pycharm(on your left upper corner) > preferences> Project > Project interpreter > +(plus sign)(the bottom of the table) >  type pandas > download

Comment: thank you. This worked for me. Everything else is too complicated!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you need to install `openssl` with `homebrew`.

```
brew install openssl
```

You can check this one: [Errors while trying to install pip from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911641/errors-while-trying-to-install-pip-from-terminal/50912124)

Comment: Did you flag it as a duplicate?

Comment: The content is not exactly the same. Maybe have different results in `Conda` or `Pycharm`.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this helps but I usually write a small python script in pycharm which imports pandas then in the script windows it will say "pandas not installed" then I just click on it and it install the library for me.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error message.
I tried eveyrthing.
It turns out that Pycharm only has pandas and numpy for professional version. Please check if you use free community version, it does not support pandas or numpy